# Selenium- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on selenium using **Firefox webdriver** and getting the following exception when the loop is running for the second time..
For the first time loop it is going fine but after closing the browser (`t.closeBrowser()`) and while executing the loop 2nd time, the error is coming up.

**Limitations :** Administrator access is not there, so soulutions like defining the range of ports etc. are not applicable.

```
            **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.**
            
            Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
            System info: host: 'NODHCMSDTP1A314', ip: '10.237.212.160', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
            Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:304)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:846)
                at WebScraper.openTestSite(WebScraper.java:18)
                at ReadExcel1.main(ReadExcel1.java:53)
            Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
                at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
                at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:233)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
                at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
                at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
                at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
                ... 4 more
            Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
                at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
                at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
                at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)... 18 more
```

```Java
      public class ReadExcel1
        {
               
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, InterruptedException
            {
                
                System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Users\\C5036344\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
                 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\C5036344\\Desktop\\test_plan_selenium.xlsx"));
                    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    WebScraper t = new WebScraper();
                   // call_author a=new call_author();
                    DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
                    
                  //  ArrayList l = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String s = new String();
                    String a1 = new String();
                    String a2 = new String();
                    String a3 = new String();
                    String a4 = new String();
                    String a5 = new String();
                    String a6 = new String();
                    String a7 = new String();
                     int i,j;
                    
                    for(i=1;i<sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;i++)
                    {
                        a1=null;
                        a2=null;
                        a3=null;
                        a4=null;
                        a5=null;
                        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
                        {
                            
                            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                                    Cell c =row.getCell(j);
                                    if(j==0){ t.openTestSite(df.formatCellValue(c)); }
                                    else if(j==8){j++; }
                                    else if(j==1){a1=df.formatCellValue(c);}
                                    else if(j==2){a2=df.formatCellValue(c);}
                                    else if(j==3){a3=df.formatCellValue(c);}
                                    else if(j==4){a4=df.formatCellValue(c);}
                                    else if(j==5){a5=df.formatCellValue(c);}
                                    else if(j==6){a6=df.formatCellValue(c);}
                                    else if(j==7){a7=df.formatCellValue(c);}
                                    
                        }
                   t.login(a4,a5,a1,a2,a3);
//System.out.println(a4+" "+a5+" "+a1+" "+a2+" "+a3+""+a7+""+a6);

                        if(t.isTextPresent("Log Out"))
                        {
                            //System.out.println(a6);
                            t.logout(a6);
                            if(t.isTextPresent("Log Out"))
                            {
                                    t.logout(a7);
                                    sheet.getRow(i).getCell(8).setCellValue("Successfull");
                                    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\C5036344\\Desktop\\test_plan_selenium.xlsx");
                                    wb.write(fos);
                                    fos.close();        
                            }
                                            
                           t.closeBrowser();
                        }
                        else
                            {
                             sheet.getRow(0).getCell(8).setCellValue("UnSuccessfull");
                             FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\C5036344\\Desktop\\test_plan_selenium.xlsx");
                             wb.write(fos);
                             fos.close();
                             t.closeBrowser();
                            }

                    }
                  
            //      a.call_me();
              }
        
}
```

Comment: Why you are closing browser in IF?

Comment: After logout only, i wanted the browser to close.It is solved now, I am not closing the browser more then one time i.e. closing after the loop is completed, resultingly it is opening in same instance not another browser and hence not asking for the port again. It was rergarding the port range issue.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious, you close the browser after the embedded loop, then try to use the browser instance that you just closed without opening it up again. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @t0mppa - Agree with you...

Comment: @AnuragDeb - you should not close browser during IF , close it at end once condition finishes.

Comment: agreed corrected.. Thanks